# RODBC in Ubuntu truncates text strings to 255 characters

Tags: sql-server, r, ubuntu, odbc

I am using RODBC installed on Ubuntu 16.0.4, and I am porting my Windows-based R project/package to this Linux environment. I am running into the issue where `sqlQuery` returns only the first 255 characters of a text string from an MS SQL Server database. I have found many references to this issue, and I have changed the column type in the database to `nvarchar(3500)` to presumably solve this issue. This was not a problem in the Windows environment. I cannot seem to get around this 255 character limit, in spite of many folks saying that changing the column variable type to `nvarchar(4000)` or less, would solve this. I've tried many things, including the `cast(...as nvarchar(1000))`, for instance, to no avail.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What about using JDBC drivers in stead of ODBC drivers?

Comment: See my fix below. I did switch drivers, but not to JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

I was using FreeTDS. I switched to native MS SQL Server drivers, and this fixed the issue. I do not know where the problem lies, but replacing FreeTDS with the MS drivers for SQL server did the trick.